# How to put dracut to initframs?

Tags: centos, selinux

I try to make SElinux `permissive`. I changed the config from `disabled` to `permissive`. However, I guess it does not recognize that change.

In the red hat web site, It says :

> If the system was initially installed without SELinux, particularly the selinux-policy package, which was added to the system later, one additional step is necessary to enable SELinux. To make sure SELinux is initialized during system startup, the dracut utility has to be run to put SELinux awareness into the initramfs file system. Failing to do so causes SELinux not to start during system startup.

How can I do that?

Comment: Reinstalling seemed to work in [this](http://serverfault.com/a/617684/252988) case. Probably, you need to verify the error messages you get and then follow the approach specified in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

It may mean that you should modify /etc/grub.conf (in my RHEL system at least) to add selinux=1 enforcing=0 to the end of your kernel line.

You may also need to rebuild your initramfs while explicitly specifying that the SELinux module should be added. (Is this done by default when the selinux-policy package is installed and dracut is run?)